# SQL conditional that searches for substring and returns 'true' or 'false'

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, substring

I need to do a mapping that is taxing my handle on SQL.

I need to know if a substring exists in a CSV contained in a table cell.  If so, I need it to return the string 'true' else 'false'

This query works in that it returns the CSV I need to check:

```
select table.value from table where table.user_id = 1 and table.keyname = 'email_list'
```

I was attempting to include that SQL inside a conditional like this:

```
IF ( (select table.value from table where table.user_id = 1 and 
table.keyname = 'email_list') LIKE '%substring%') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
```

But no luck so far. This is actually one component of a much bigger query mapping different elements from one table to another so I really need it to just return a string of 'true' or 'false' for it to work appropriately.

Table structure looks something like this:

```
User   KEYNAME        value (in the form of CSV)
1       email_list   george@gmail.com, george@yahoo.com
2       email_list   
3       email_list   kiley@yahoo.com
4       email_list   kim@gmail.com, kimmy@hotmail.com, wondergirl@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Please show several rows of sample data which make clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: try using Case statement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a **CASE** statement inside the select clause should solve your problem.

Something like the below

```
select case when table.value LIKE '%substring%' 
        then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as "Result" 
from table where table.user_id = 1 and 
table.keyname = 'email_list'
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about not accepting the answer.  If you have a moment, I'm wondering what the 'end as "Result" in the query is for?

Comment: END is to end the case statement, it is a syntax. AS "result" is just an alias column name to the resultant column.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT table.value
FROM table
WHERE EXISTS
(select table.value FROM table WHERE table.user_id = 1 AND table.keyname = 'email_list' AND table.value LIKE '%substring%');`

I hope this will solve the issue.